# Google Map API invalid Value Error Function not defined?

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-maps

I'm new to javascript and not too familiar with the google API integration. I'm just trying to load a simple page with a google map for testing. I've seen different implementations and can really discern any differences which might be giving me errors in this little code block. Can anyone tell me why I am getting getting this error?

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> MAP </TITLE>
</HEAD>

<SCRIPT src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
key=**keyhere**&callback=initialize"></script>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE ="JavaScript">

function initialize(){
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 3, 
center: {lat:51.500, lng:-0.201}});
}

</SCRIPT>


</BODY onload= "initialize()">
<div id="map" style="width:500px; height:400px;"></div>
<BODY>


<HTML>
```

Comment: for some reason the screenshot didnt upload... heres the error:

mc {message: "initialize is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new mc (https://maps.googleapis.com/m…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax errors in your HTML, this is incorrect:

```
</BODY onload= "initialize()">
<div id="map" style="width:500px; height:400px;"></div>
<BODY>
```

should be:

```
<BODY onload= "initialize()">
<div id="map" style="width:500px; height:400px;"></div>
</BODY>
```

You also don't need/want two calls to initialize (one in the body onload, the other in the API callback parameter), remove one.

Working code:

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> MAP </TITLE>
</HEAD>

<SCRIPT src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initialize" async defer ></script>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE ="JavaScript">

function initialize(){
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 3, 
center: {lat:51.500, lng:-0.201}});
}

</SCRIPT>


<BODY>
<div id="map" style="width:500px; height:400px;"></div>
</BODY>


<HTML>
```